# Change image of an object

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to make so that when I run a function it changes the image of objects in a function and I thought this would work

```
for(var i = 0; i < heads.length; i++){heads[i].src = ram_head;}
```

with ram_head equaling a string with the url but when I run the code the image does not change at all when I run the function.

Example of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/themagicalcake/URvA7

Comment: What are `heads` and `ram_head`?  You'll have to show us more of your code for us to know what's going on.  Changing the `.src` property on an `<image>` tag to a proper image URL will change the image that shows.

Comment: heads is an array with objects with an image atribute and I said what ram head is

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what "array with objects with an image attribute" is.  If you're serious about getting help here, you'll show us the rest of the relevant code rather than make us ask 20 questions just to try to figure out how to help you.  Right now you have an incomplete question that only discloses about 30% of what people who might want to help need to know.

Comment: `function head() { 
  this.img = new Image();
  this.img.src = "~link~";
}`

Comment: jsfiddle.net/themagicalcake/URvA7 here's a fiddle to show what my problem is

Answer (score 0):

Here's code that:

- creates an array of image objects (heads)
- assigns the same image URL to all of those image objects (rams_head)
- and when each image has fully loaded draws that image to the canvas.

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/5DXe7/

```
var ram_head="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/RAMDISEGNO.jpg";

var heads=[];
heads.push(new Image());
heads.push(new Image());

for(var i=0;i<heads.length;i++){

    heads[i].onload=function(){
        ctx.drawImage(this,this.x,10);
    }

    heads[i].x=i*100;

    heads[i].src=ram_head;

}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I have objects in my array already and i want to change the image of all of them but it is not working

Comment: That's exactly what the for-loop does in my answer!  It takes an array of image objects and changes all the images to the image fetched in ram_head. I also draw the images on the canvas as a "proof-of-concept", but you don't have to do that if your design doesn't require it.  I presented example code because the code you show in your question should work.  If it doesn't, then the trouble is outside the code you offer--which is why jfriend00 requested more code from you :-/

Comment: So you are saying that `for(var i = 0; i < heads.length; i++){heads[i].src=ram_head;}` would work, becausre that is what i have.

Comment: Yes, it would work...see my working Demo.  Again(!), if this is not working for you then the problem with your code is *outside the small bit of code you've given us.*

Comment: The thing is that everything else inside that function works so I don't see how it could be a different part

Comment: I can't help debug code that you refuse to show...Good luck with your project.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/themagicalcake/URvA7/
When I click, it does not change the image

Comment: I mean when I press a key

Answer (score 0):

I see three issues with the code you've now linked to:

1. When you set the `.src` of an Image object, you can't use that image to draw with until the new `.src` URL image has loaded.  If you want to change the `.src` and then draw, you have to handle the onload event and draw when that fires.
2. In your `onkeydown` handler, you are setting `heads[i].src`, but the image object is `heads[i].img` so the `.src` of the image would be `heads[i].img.src`.
3. Since you aren't displaying native `<img>` tags in the DOM, but are instead drawing the image yourself, after you change the `.src` of the image and then wait for that new image to load, if you want the image to display in your drawing context, you have to redraw it yourself.  I won't just redraw just because you changed the `.src`.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are saying with the first point. And also I forgot to include the `setInterval` code in the code I linked.

Comment: Also I just realized that if I were to add more objects to the array they would not have the new image. How can I change the constructors `.img.src` ?

Comment: @user3236691 - sorry, I can't really help you further without understanding the overall problem you're trying to solve.  Your current code makes no sense to me because you may as well us an `<img>` inserted in the DOM, not draw it manually for what you're doing and I see no reason for having a `head` object either as you can just put an identifier on the `<img>` object.  So, without understanding what you're actually trying to do, I don't know what code to recommend and I don't want to build further without a goal I understand.